# passing a pointer of a reference/passing a reference of a reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Do I get a usual pointer as I pass a pointer to a reference of a variable or do i get a pointer to the reference? And what do i get as I pass a reference to a reference?
I am using the stack implementation of the [standard library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/stack/top/) in a class, and i want to have some wrapper methods to prevent illegal access of the stack, but i am getting strange segfaults which i narrowed down to my getter-methods considering the stack.

Should those methods give back a clean reference/pointer to the original variable stored in the stack?

```
int& zwei() { return stack.top() };
```

and

```
int* eins() { return &stack.top() };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "pointer to a reference". References are aliases, and so taking the address of any of them will give a pointer to the same object:

```
int a;
int & b = a;

assert(&a == &b);
```

Your functions both return a valid result provided that the `stack` object is still alive in the scope of the function return.

```
std::stack<int> s;

int & foo() { return s.top(); }  // OK, maybe
int * goo() { return &s.top(); } // ditto

int & boo() { std::stack<int> b; return b.top(); } // No! Dangling reference!
```

You should also check that the stack isn't empty, in which case `top()` is not valid.

(I should also council against calling a variable by the same name as a type, even though the type's name is `std::stack`.)

Comment: what do you mean by "OK, maybe"?

Comment: @Sim: He said what "OK, maybe" means right before that: *Your functions both return a valid result* **provided that** *the* `stack` *object is still alive*. And after the code: *You should also check that the stack isn't empty*. That "provided that" and "non-empty stack" are what he meant by "OK, maybe".

Comment: @Sim: The stack mustn't be empty for `top()` to be valid. The code as written doesn't include any insertions to `s`, so it's possible that the `foo()` and `goo()` are *not* OK, and it depends on *you*. On the other hand, `boo()` is never OK.

Comment: ok, i didn't link the maybe with the fact that the stack might be in some limbo state. I misunderstood it as an uncertainty of the author.